# ADFS on same server setup SSO

Tags: .net, sharepoint, adfs2.0

I am in the process of configuring my AFDS. The two applications I am attempting to have trust  each other are on the same server, under the same doamin. I was wondering if anybody has any particular experience with configuring ADFS on a single server with the applications on the same server as well.

Thanks!

Are there any guides to this, or any special configurations I need for my situation? Do I need to do anything special with the certificates, since both applications and ADFS are on the same server?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: sorry, I added some questions

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why you would do such a thing - it's a bit too much for a single server as I understand it. However, I would suppose you need to configure the trusts just as you would with a two server setup.

I have successfully configured it for sharepoint 2013 using this tutorial:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx

Also, we have set up a custom login page using the following tutorial:
http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=76

It's for sharepoint 2010 but everything is mostly the same. Please pay attention to copying the thumbprints to sharepoint's web.config - if you copy them straight from the window, an invisible unicode character is copied with them. You can't see it in a text editor but SharePoint most definitely sees it and will throw an ID4175 error.

If you stumble on any problems please don't hesitate to comment on this thread so I get a notification.

Comment: Hi Rafal, thanks for information. I should have also specified, that I am working on a single sign on approach to work with both .NET and SharePoint 2010. Is there another approach you would have for this situation? I am stuck between 
AFDS and configuring the machine keys, domain, etc to be the same between the two applications. Both applications will be hosted on the same domain and on the same server.

Comment: Well, I only have some experience with setting up ADFS - I cannot be of help if you want to look for other solutions, as I am not aware of any. Configuring adfs is not that much work however, and having it on the same domain should only make things faster.